# ¿Cómo alinear (left,center,righ) de lineas de un Textview en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy batellando que algunas lineas de un `TextView` se pueda alinear a la izquierda, derecha o centro.

Entiendo que se debe realizar con `SpannableString` y su alineación
`AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment...)`

- ALIGN_NORMAL
- ALIGN_CENTER
- ALIGN_OPPOSITE

Dejo parte del banco de pruebas

```
String str1 = "linea justificada a la izquierda";
String str2 = "linea centrada";
String str3 = "linea justificada a la derecha"

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug_log);

tv.append(...)
```

¿Cómo se implementa un `SpannableString` con su alineación?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes emplear el siguiente método

```
 appendText(str1, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL);
 appendText(str2, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
 appendText(str3, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE);

private void appendText(CharSequence text, Layout.Alignment align) {
    if (text == null || text.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    AlignmentSpan span = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(align);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, text.length(), 0);

    tvPruebas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pruebas);

    if (tvPruebas.length() > 0) {
        tvPruebas.append("\n\n");
    }
    tvPruebas.append(spannableString);
}
```

y obtienes el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y donde se carga tvPruebas con findViewById etc..

Comment: tvPruebas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pruebas);

Comment: Me refiero, es lo que le falta al código

Answer (score 2):

Basandome con la respuesta de @Bourne he modificado su solución, para así puede usarse en cualquier `TextView` que tengamos en la App.

**Función appendTextAlignment**

```
private void appendTexAlignment(final TextView tv, Layout.Alignment align, CharSequence text) {
    if (text == null || text.toString().trim().length() == 0) { return; }

    AlignmentSpan span = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(align);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, text.length(), 0);

    if (tv != null) {
        tv.append(spannableString);
    }
}
```

**Su uso**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug_log);

appendTextAlignment(tv,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,"Izquierda\n");
appendTextAlignment(tv,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,"Centrado\n");
appendTextAlignment(tv,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE,"Derecha\n");
```